# React Map is not reading properties

Tags: reactjs, react-map-gl, react-class-based-component

I am learning react. It is showing an error. I tried many time to solve it but failed. I tried changing `this.state.article` with `this.article` but in vein- I even tried to cover this in function but it didn't work.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    console.log("let see If this constructor is running");
        this.state = {
            article : [],
            loading : false
        }
    
}  
 async componentDidMount(){
  let url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=pakistan&apiKey=api-key"
  let data  = await fetch(url);
  let parsedData = await data.json()
  console.log(parsedData);
  this.setState({article: parsedData.article})
}
```

render() {

```
return <div>
    <div className='justify-content-center container my-5'>
    <h1>Muzamil's News - Headlines</h1>
    <div className='container row'>
     {this.state.article.map((element)=>{
      console.log("why it is not working");
      return <div key={element.url} className="col-md-4">
        <NewsItem title={element.title} description={element.description}
        urlToImage={element.urlToImage} url={element.url}></NewsItem>
      </div>
    })}
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try replacing: `{this.state.article.map((element)=>{` with `{this.state && this.state.article && Array.isArray(this.state.article) && this.state.article.map((element)=>{`

Answer (score 1):

If your component  not showing anything its probably because article array is still empty . You can specify what is the error you are facing?

Comment: I have console.log(article); and It shows articles in console

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the API in the correct way, so try the following steps :

1. Go to [API link](https://newsapi.org/register) and create account
2. The website will give you the API Key copy it and past it in your link, example [https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=pakistan&apiKey=[Your_API_Key]](https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=pakistan&apiKey=%5BYour_API_Key%5D)
3. Use the correct keys of the data (use "articles" instead of "article" in fetch) :
   [image: data structure]

Comment: Thanks, The only issue was I was using article instead of articles but the api Was providing me with Json Named Articles

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding :)